# implementing tagkeys on simple-json-datassource grafana

Tags: datasource, grafana, datastore

I am trying to implement tag-keys with simple-json-datasourece.

I am having hard-time getting the values populated to the dropdown menu. Everytime I select(click) on a value, its getting undefined "value"

Anyone have tried this implementation?